# For what class of distribution is this function concave?

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, continuous-data

consider the following sorted sample:

$x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_n$

and the kernel function:

$h(j)=\log(x_j-x_1), j>1$.

Now, it turns out that when I draw data 
from many continuous distributions, sort
 them and compute $h(j)$, the plot of the
 $h(j)$ as a function of $j$ is concave in 
 this sense: $h((j+k)/2)>(h(j)+h(k))/2$ 
for $1<j<j+1<k<n$

My question is the following: will this 
observation (concavity of $h(j)$ as a 
function of $j$) be true for all continuous
 distributions? If not is there a class 
of distributions for which it will always be 
true?

Thanks in advance,

At this point, given the useful comments from @Glen_b and @Momo,
I think I should give an example.

this is a vector of values of $x_j-x_1,j>1$ (where the $x$'s are drawn from 
a continuous distribution, but have been rounded here to the third digit 
so that they don't take too much place.)

My problem, is that when I plot $h(j)$ for this data-set, the result is clearly 
nor concave (in the sense I outlined above).

```
x=c(1.403, 1.406, 1.408, 1.416, 1.417, 1.42, 1.427, 1.441, 1.448, 
1.456, 1.458, 1.465, 1.466, 1.472, 1.472, 1.477, 1.477, 1.479, 
1.482, 1.491, 1.5, 1.504, 1.518, 1.52, 1.52, 1.53, 1.544, 1.545, 
1.561, 1.573, 1.595, 1.595, 1.599, 1.603, 1.605, 1.612, 1.617, 
1.618, 1.618, 1.628, 1.64, 1.644, 1.646, 1.653, 1.679, 1.682, 
1.682, 1.693, 1.694, 1.71, 1.71, 1.711, 1.741, 1.75, 1.756, 1.773, 
1.794, 1.799, 1.804, 1.808, 1.86, 1.882, 1.895, 1.955, 1.992, 
1.995, 2.009, 2.009, 2.063, 2.123, 2.329, 2.356, 2.405, 2.535, 
2.632, 2.635, 2.725, 2.763, 2.783)
```

Comment: I'm curious where the distribution comes in here. Is $x_i$ a random variable and possibky  different for each $i$  or a realisation and thus a real number ?

Comment: @Momo: thanks for your question but I do not understand it. Can you try to re-phrase please? Thanks.

Comment: I'll try: You talk about continuous distributions. I wonder if $x$ is a random variable with an arbitrary distribution or if it is a real number.

Comment: The concavity of the *function* $h$ doesn't depend on the distribution of the values of the arguments you apply it to. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Glen_b: thanks for your comment. Are you stating that so long as the xi are drawn from a continuous distribution, h(j) will always be concave, in the sense made precise in my question? Sorry if the question sounds naive, I'm not a statistician.

Comment: @Momo: with probability 1 x is a real number, since it is drawn from a continuous distribution.

Comment: What @Glen_b and I try to tell you that your question has nothing to do with distributions. Please clarify what it is you want to know. The natural logarithm  is concave for positive real numbers.

Comment: @user42397 Distributions don't seem to come into it at all. See the definition of 'concave function', for example, at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function). Perhaps you mean to ask a somewhat different question, which is why I asked you to clarify. You can check if $h$ is concave by reference to that definition, without even bringing up the concept of random variables.

Comment: "$h((j+k)/2)$" doesn't even make sense unless $j+k$ is even! Consider the case $j=1,k=3$. You ask when $h(2)\le(h(1)+h(3))/2,$ for that situation would violate concavity. That merely requires $h(3)$ to be sufficiently large compared to $h(1)$ and $h(2)$. For *any* continuous distribution this event has a positive probability. What, then, are you really trying to ask?

Comment: I'm still having trouble following what this question is actually getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED:

the problem is related to transformation which preserves concavity of the log function. here we transform an index $j$ into real numbers $x(j)$, then transform the real numbers with $\ln(.)$ function, i.e. $h(j) = \ln(x(j))$ , $ln(.)$ is concave, now the transformation $x(j)$ must be at least not more convex than $\ln(.)$ is concave.

e.g. $e^{x^2}$ is *too convex* because the sequence $\{0,1,2\}$ becomes $h(j)=\{0,1,\ln(4)\}$, which is convex.

in this case $x(j)$ transformation is not a simple function, but a probabilistic one. it seems to me that for a large sample probability to get a concave sequence should tend to be zero for any distribution.

Comment: This is incorrect. Take, for instance, the dataset $(0,e,e,e^2)$, for which $h(2)=\log(e-0)=1,h(3)=\log(e-0)=1,h(4)=\log(e^2-0)=2$, whence $1=h(3)\lt(h(2)+h(4))/2=3/2,$ contradicting your assertion.

Comment: $x_j-x_1=\{e,2e,2e+e^2\}$ not $x_j-x_1=\{e,e,e^2\}$

Comment: Your are responding to an earlier version of my comment, which I fixed while you were posting yours. But even so, if you do the calculation with $(e, 2e, 2e+e^2)$ you will *still* find this is a counterexample. The point is that concavity of the log is irrelevant when the subject concerns the values of the finite sequence $(x_j-x_1).$

Comment: got it. so the problem then is $h(j)=\ln(x(j))$ , $\ln$ is concave, now the transformation $x(j)$ must be at least not more convex than $\ln$ is concave

Comment: That is an excellent analysis: you got to the heart of it.

Comment: @Aksakal, whuber: thanks to both, I think we're getting close to a good explanation. Now, I can rephrase my question as 'is there a class of distributions $x$ such that $x_{(j)}-x_{(1)},j>1$ is *not more convex than $\ln$ is concave*'

Comment: @user603, your current description is fine. it seems that unimodal distributions will not have that property

Comment: @Aksakal: if you could update your answer, I will be happy to throw reps your way.

Comment: The *only* distributions with that characteristic are *discrete* ones whose values have been carefully chosen. No distribution that has a continuous component will have that property. Specifically, there will be strictly positive probability of obtaining a sample for which your concavity criterion does not hold.

Comment: The limited domain distributions such as beta should be fine